# Migrating from Azure SDK 2.0 to Azure SDK 2.3

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net

We have critical project partly deployed in azure that uses queues, blobs and table storage.
Now we using SDK 2.0 and thinking about moving to latest SDK 2.3 but it will cost us some resources especially for load testing with a new Azure SDK.

Is there a strong point to update SDK version like critical bug fix, performance issue or maybe useful new feature?
Sure, I read release notes but haven't found enough information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we recommend that you always take the latest storage client from Nuget directly. If you look at Nuget you will see we are actually on 4.0.1 version of the .NET client vs the 2.0 version of the storage client that I believe is what shipped with SDK 2.0. As you can imagine there are a very large list of improvements between client 2.0 and 4.0. A couple of quick examples include: CORS Support, large improvements to Tables including JSON support and a highly optimized table service layer.

Here are some blogs with some more information:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/05/14/what-s-new-for-microsoft-azure-storage-at-teched-2014.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/05/windows-azure-tables-introducing-json.aspx

There are also a lot of performance related improvements that have been made as well:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/09/07/announcing-storage-client-library-2-1-rtm.aspx

Hope this helps.

Jason

Answer (score 0):

The latest Storage SDK version is now v12, which you can find in the Azure SDK repos:

- [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage)
- [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage)
- [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage)
- [JS/TS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/storage)

You can also find migration guides in the repos which detail the migration benefits. The SDK has now split into separate ones like Storage Blob, Storage Queue, etc. The following are migration guides for Storage Blob. You can find the guides for the others in the repos as well:

- [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/migrationGuides)
- [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/AzureStorageNetMigrationV12.md)

Finally, there are Changelogs for the new SDKs in the repos as well, which you can reference to see what fixes/changes are done. The following are Changelogs for Storage Blob. You can find the logs for Queue, Datalake, etc. in the repos as well:

- [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/CHANGELOG.md)
- [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/CHANGELOG.md)
- [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/CHANGELOG.md)
- [JS/TS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/storage/storage-blob/CHANGELOG.md)

It is recommended that you use the latest SDKs since those are the ones getting the new features as well as bug and critical fixes whereas the older libraries will only be getting bug and critical fixes. Read more about [Azure SDK lifecycle and support policy](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/policies_support.html#azure-sdk-lifecycle-and-support-policy)