# Windows Azure Storage: What SDK version uses? (4.0.1 vs 2.3 Azure SDK)

Tags: nuget-package, azure-sdk-.net, azure-storage

I am a little confused with the (1)[Azure SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn655054.aspx) and the (2)[Windows Azure Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/4.0.1) nu-get package **versions**.
Can someone explain what version of the SDK (latest 2.3) uses the latest nu-get package (4.0.1 is the latest currently).
In the MSDN(1) says the 2.3 release contains "Azure Storage 3.0".

It looks like a complete mess...

It is strange that after updating the nu-get package, it removed the references to the old 'StorageClient.dll', and did not added the new assembly. Instead it added other dependencies.

I am starting to think are these 2 one and the same thing? There is already a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949693/migrating-from-azure-sdk-2-0-to-azure-sdk-2-3), that adds more confusion.
Will i be safe with just updating the nu-get package(2), or i need to run the SDK  installer(1) first? Is the nu-get package(2) just the wrapper around the Client Api(1)

There are a lot of breaking changes, but this is due to the big jump in the versions i suppose, but just wanted to confirm I am on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

After closing/reopening the solution I found the answer.VS prompted that i do not have the SDK installed and asked me to download it, so everything seems fine.

The **Azure SDK used is 2.3** (Windows Azure Tools)

It also updated the Cloud configuration's schemaVersion to "2014-01.2.3", so it is wrapping around the latest Azure Client API.

[image: Windows Azure Tools Propmt]

Answer (score 0):

The Storage Client library ships on both nuget and as part of the Azure SDK. Because the storage client libraries evolve at a faster rate (we generally release an update to nuget every 6 – 7 weeks) than the SDK you will typically see the latest versions of the client libraries on nuget. In general we recommend that people get the latest version of the client libraries directly from nuget. The SDK does of course provide a convenient way to obtain other Azure service client libraries plus tools such as the emulators – so it can be a useful way to download everything at once in order to get started with all Azure services.

For the storage client libraries you can find a good overview of each client library release on the [Azure Storage Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/) - so depending on what version you are migrating from you might want to review relevant posts to learn more about the changes. You can also find some pointers to upgrading guidance that I posted on a different thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23949693/migrating-from-azure-sdk-2-0-to-azure-sdk-2-3/23976509#23976509).

Jason